# Python: Writing text with a width seperator?

Tags: python

I was something that looks like this:

```
-----hello------
```

Now I know I can get the symbols to print by defining and printing a width, but how do I insert text within it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
print 'hello'.center(16,'-')
```

Or like this:

```
print '{:-^16}'.format("hello")
```

That will set the width to `16` and pad the string with `'-'`.

Check the tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_center.htm).

Comment: Width should be 16 to get a result similar to the question.

Comment: @BasSwinckels, oh yes, thank you

Comment: My question may be unclear, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @ToshibaA, you're always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

use string formatting

```
"-----%s------" %("hello")
"-----{}------".format("hello")
```